# Can't choose framework for segmentation_models library in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a ResNet34 model using **segmentation_models**(sm) library in python. The **sm** library uses **keras framework** by default when importing, but I am working with **tf.keras** to build my datasets used for training and testing.

The documentation says that in order to change the default framework I should either use an environmental variable `SM_FRAMEWORK=tf.keras` before importing (which I tried but it didn't work) or set it using the method `set_framework` (which doesn't show up in the suggestions/it says it doesn't exist when I try to execute it).

Is there any other way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I trained model on colab and I used :"%env SM_FRAMEWORK=tf.keras" to set the environment to tf.keras and it worked perfectly.